# How to use Jquery effects (explode) on newly created elements

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a div element explode then reappear.  This part works fine, but when the new div is created, the explode effect will not work on the copy.

Here's my Jquery:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#thediv").click(function(){
            $("#thediv").effect('explode');
            $(".mainBody").append("<div id='thediv'> </div>");
        });
    });
```

Here's my Html:

```
    <div class="mainBody" align = "center">
        <div id="thediv" style=" width: 100px; height: 100px; background-image: url('http://smartisan.net/stripes.png')"></div>
    </div>
```

and here's the page if you want to see it:[Right Here](http://smartisan.net/fun/jquerytest)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a jQuery effect / animation doesnt remove the element from the DOM, it just hide it. So you just need use the complete callback to set it visible again.

```
$("#thediv").click(function(){
     $("#thediv").effect('explode', function() {
         $(this).show()
     });
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/HBepC/1/

Comment: @WillemHunt welcome to stackoverflow. If this indeed solved your problem you should use the green arrow to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click","#thediv",function(){
        $("#thediv").effect('explode');
        $(".mainBody").append("<div id='thediv'> </div>");
    });
});
```

Use "on" with name of event to bind dynamically loaded elements

Comment: That is the same has doing the click, You are delegating the event to "#thediv" but once it is removed the event is also gone. You need to delegate it to at least on parent level up. fix it and i'll remove the downvote

Comment: Also, I'm sure that explode does not delete element so $("#thediv").css("display","block"); insted of append would work.